# How to sum values returned from web Api Query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum, reduce, webapi

would it be possible to sum the following values using pure `JavaScript`/ `(jQuery)` :

```
$("#val_1").text();
$("#val_2").text();
$("#val_3").text();

// add the reduce or sum function here.


// place result into an element:

$("#result").val();

// append result into the html here:

$('[data-name="section"] tbody').find('td').first().append('<tr><td class="clearfix cell"><h4>'+ result +
'</h4></td></tr>');
}
```

your help is much appreciated!

kind regards,
MRowan

I have tried without success `reduce()` and jquery `sum`.